# Hide menu when ESC clicked using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently customising an off-screen navigation menu.

I'd like to use Javascript to close the menu when ESC is clicked or if the user clicks outside of the menu's focus. How do I achieve this?

Here's my example: http://jsfiddle.net/q55xtcw4/

I've tried using this code:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
    if ( $( e.target ).closest( elem ).length === 0 ) {
        $( elem ).hide();
    }
});

$( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) { // ESC
        $( elem ).hide();
    }
});
```

but no success.

Many thanks for any guidance here.

Comment: Where is it failing? On detecting the keypress, or on identifying the keycode as 27, or on hiding the element.  If you use a breakpoint in the code and step through you should be able to 'see' what doesn't work.

Comment: from where `elem` comes?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be acknowledging the ESC keyprress at all.

Comment: And don't go for click event it's pure css navigation with click!

Comment: Your example has an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: elem is not defined`. Who's `elem`?

Comment: what is this "elem" in u r code

Comment: Even if you fix the elem issue I think your code will break.  You're mixing a 'pure' CSS solution with javascript. Once you hide the side menu you will not be able to show it again - it will be hidden.

Comment: What is rather surprising is that the menu is actually working, despide elem is not defined and that, therefore both click and keydown events are absolutely pointless right now, lol.

Comment: @briosheje - it's a dirty css hack using a hidden checkbox and transitions.   Far too clever for its own good if you ask me :)

Comment: @JamesGaunt : Indeed, just noticed right now how complex that CSS is, lol. That's evil.

Comment: Haha - I'm sorry for my evil code lol :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e9wa0093/2/

Basically, `elem` wasn't defined in your example. Same with `show()` and `hide()` methods. The changes I made to your code merely updates the `checked` property of the hidden checkbox used to control the position (i.e., visibility) of the menu.

**Edit:**

Corrected JSFiddle, as commented below: http://jsfiddle.net/e9wa0093/4/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I click the menu icon, it reveals. When I click again, it doesn't close. Help?

Answer (score 1):

Dirty but useful solution for you change your JS code into this

```
$(".nav-trigger").click(function(e){e.stopPropagation()})
$( document ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {

    $( ".nav-trigger" ).prop("checked",false);

});

$( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
  if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) { // ESC
      $( ".nav-trigger" ).prop("checked",false);
  }
});
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q55xtcw4/4/)

here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q55xtcw4/6/)

Comment: That's a clever solution :)

Comment: With this solution, when I click the menu icon, it reveals, click again and it doesn't close. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Use This :-

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) $('.save').click();     // enter
      if (e.keyCode == 27) $('.cancel').click();   // esc
    });
```

[FOR more info click here](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

Answer (score 0):

elem is not something on your DOM

```
$( elem ).hide();
```

you should change it into your class or id like:

```
$('#menu').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $(document).keypress(function (evt) {
       //Determine where our character code is coming from within the event
       var charCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
       if (charCode  == 27) { //Enter key's keycode
         //do what ever you want
         $('#someid').hide();
       }
     });
   }); 


 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are using is based on a CSS hack using a hidden checkbox.

You can control the status of the menu by toggling the value of this checkbox, rather than using javascript to hide the menu.  Hiding the menu using javascript will actually break the CSS hack, as the CSS depends on the menu being visible but just offset from the side of the screen.

So replace:

```
$( elem ).hide();
```

With:

```
$("#nav-trigger").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will collapse the menu on pressing escape

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 27) { $("#nav-trigger").removeAttr("checked") }   
});
```